# Retrieving Bags To Clear Customs/Lounge Access Upon Arrival

Tags: customs-and-immigration, luggage, american-airlines, lounges, jal

I will be travelling from NRT -> ORD -> EWR next year. When I land in ORD, will I need to retrieve my bags in order to clear US customs?

Also, my flight from NRT to ORD is with JAL in business class, and my flight from ORD to EWR is with AA in first class. Will I have Admiral's Club/Flagship Lounge access in ORD with my JAL business class ticket? (I know that the domestic first class is ineligible for club/lounge access).

Comment: Provided this is a single ticket, lounge access should be fine since you are travelling with an international business ticket on a one world partner. https://www.oneworld.com/airport-lounges?location=ORD However, access rules have gotten so convoluted that you an never tell for sure.

Comment: What do you mean by single ticket? @Hilmar

Comment: Single ticket means it's a single reservation/itinerary for the the entire flight . If it's two separate tickets, the JAL Business class will not carry over to the AA part of the flight

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, with inbound flights into the US, everyone clears customs at the first port of entry (ie ORD in your case) irrespective if they're transiting  domestically or internationally.

From [CBP.gov](https://www.cbp.gov/travel/international-visitors/know-before-you-visit):

> *Everyone* **arriving at a port of entry to the U.S. is subject to inspection by Customs** and Border Protection officers for compliance with immigration, customs and agriculture regulations.

For one to clear customs, they must get their luggage at the first port of entry (ORD in your case) go through customs and recheck-in the luggage from the domestic terminal to fly from ORD to EWR.

---

There is American Flagship Lounge and American/JAL/Iberia (Admiral's Club) lounges in ORD according to  [ORD's website](https://www.flychicago.com/ohare/ServicesAmenities/services/Pages/lounges.aspx), both being in the terminal 3 of the domestic terminal:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

All passengers arriving in an US airport, in this case, O'Hare International Airport, Have to pass through immigration, collect baggage and recheck the luggage themselves.

There are no exceptions, even if you are transiting to a third country.

Comment: No, there are exceptions, which I used few times. I'm not sure if Delta in ATL still make it, it was an experimental test, but I used it several for several years. Immigration is mandatory, and also passing the custom (but just with cabin baggage).